# Heroku multi buildpack with nginx, java and node

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, nginx, buildpack

I have a node app which contains a node plugin that references a jar file. My question is this - 
Is there a specific example of a heroku multi buildpack which loads all three -

```
...nginx.git
...java.git
...nodejs.git
```

In my root I have the following:

```
.buildpacks
.nginx
system.properties
package.json
```

Also, if this is a native nodejs app that is dependant upon a plugin which refrences a jar file and hence need to load the java environment, is it necessary that I also include a POM.XML file in my application's root?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the Java buildpack, use the [jvm-common buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common). This way, you won't need a `pom.xml`. You can put this line in your `.buildpacks` file:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common
```

Or set it with the `heroku buildpacks` command.

Comment: Why not/can't Java-buildpack?

Comment: In this case, the user doesn't need Maven. If you need Maven and you have a pom.xml then the java buildpack will work in place of the jvm-common buildpack